# Force the browser to download videos from third party website

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this problem. I have a website which has URLs to videos from different website (not in my servers). What I exactly want when the user clicks on any of these link the video in remote website is downloaded.
 But what I have now when the user clicks on the link the video is open and show on the browser instead of download. 
I created a source code in ASP.net and C# that could force the browser to download the video, but the problem here is that my server should process the downloading operation to the browser, in other word that data should pass through my server to the client browser rather than from the third website to the client directly.

This will have two problems

1. it waste my server resources and effectiveness because the data should be processed through the server
2. it will increase the In and out bandwidth for my server and all the files are videos so it will be very costly.

What I want now, is there a way that enables me to force the browser to download the file directly from third party and without passing data through my server by using JavaScript, jQuery, or any client side techniques?

Comment: You can not force the browser you can just request the browser. The browser has it's own setting which varies user to user. And if the path of the video is of other site than it will loaded from other site rather than your site.

Comment: Yes I know it will be downloaded from the other website, but it downloaded via my website.  I am thinking in a way that I can set the URL to be downloaded as attachment not open

Answer (score -1):

The html5 `download` attribute could help here. I haven't tested it personally but [this blogpost](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) says adding `download` should force a download on the browser side.

Example code:

```
<a href="http://some.com/random/path/" download="video.mp4">Download</a>
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response, I tried your solution it is work only on Google chrome browser. it dose not work in Firefox and IE.

Comment: ah shame :( then I don't think there's a way to do this clientside for those browsers